# restricting output values in keras layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, restriction

i have written this NN

```
decoder_output = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_input)
decoder_output = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder_output)
decoder_output = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder_output)
decoder_output = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder_output)
decoder_output = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder_output)
decoder_output = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder_output)
decoder_output = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(decoder_output)
decoder_output = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder_output)
decoder_output = Flatten()(decoder_output)
decoder_output = Dense(height*width, activation='relu')(decoder_output)
model = Model(inputs=encoder_input, outputs=decoder_output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
clean_images = model.fit(train_images, y_train_red, epochs=10,validation_data=(validation_images,y_validation_red))
```

which suppose to return an image values.
is there a way to restrict the return values to be int and/or maximize the ouput layer value to 255?

Comment: You can follow [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2221)

Answer (score 0):

What should happen is that your model will learn to not output values above 255 and below 0. However, in the instances that it does, you could clip the values to be between 0 and 255 when you are predicting. Regarding integer outputs, there isn't a way that I know of. However, you could round the outputs when you are predicting.